# ShowDialog Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match

Tags: flutter, dialog

I was launch RatingDialog using showDialog like:

```
void _showRatingDialog(driverId,voteNb,ratingOld) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: true, // set to false if you want to force a rating
            builder: (context) {
              return RatingDialog(
                icon: Image.asset('images/logo-light.png'),
                title: "Evaluation ",
                description:  
                    "évaluer votre voyage.",
                submitButton: "Envoyer",
                alternativeButton: "Fermer", // optional
                positiveComment: "Satisfié :)", // optional
                negativeComment: "Pas du tout :(", // optional
                accentColor: ThemeUtils.blue, // optional
                onSubmitPressed: (int rating) async {
                  await driverRatingUpdate.save();
                },
                onAlternativePressed: () {
                  print("onAlternativePressed: do something");
                },
              );
            });
      }
```

it works fine yesterday but now when I try to launch it brings an error:

> /C:/Taxi_App/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/locally-0.2.6+9/lib/locally.dart:126:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'child'.
> child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
> ^^^^^ /C:/Taxi_App/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart:1035:12:
> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
>
> Future<T?> showDialog({
> ^^^^^^^^^^
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\Taxi_App\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>   line: 991

plz guys help me !!!

Edit: Ifound that the problem is general not in that piece of code, the app wan't run at all.

btw my flutter version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the context and pass it to showDialog

```
void _showRatingDialog(BuildContext context   /*here*/  , driverId,voteNb,ratingOld) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
```

Comment: ok I have paased my context as Global variable like : `BuildContext contextGlobal;` then I fill it on build widget by paasing local contaxt value to it like: `contextGlobal = context;` then I use the global Context on my dialog as:` showDialog(
            context: contextGlobal,`
but there is the same error here

Comment: I think the problem is with 
Null safety new flutter function mmm but I don't know

Comment: also I have tried to use `Get.context` but also the same error

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, 
please try to run this after downgrading to 1.x stable release